# Using Fetch for CSV in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, csv, fetch

```
const response = await fetch('Reddit_data.csv');
const data = await response.text();
console.log(data);
```

The above code works for me in Visual Studio however I cant figure out how to get it to read the csv once in the html block in wordpress.
I have tried csv importer plugins but I just cant workout where I should save the csv in order to get access to my data inside my Wordpress page.

Comment: What exactly is the end goal? Are you trying to display a table?

Comment: Aim is to display a chart using chart.js. Which again I have working in Visual studio locally. Im assuming I need to get my csv onto my websites server?

Comment: Yes, you definitely need to upload it. You could create a `csv` folder in `wp-content/uploads`, then use `fetch("/wp-content/uploads/csv/reddit_data.csv")`

Comment: Chris you legend! Wp-content is the step in logic I have been missing. Got it all working!